# Can unicode characters be generated from unicode literals in QGIS expressions?

Tags: qgis, unicode

I know that unicode characters can be copied and pasted into expressions in QGIS, but can they be generated from a unicode literal ie `u'\u00C9'` without using a custom Python function?